Losing data after returning from method (Arduino uno and Sim900)
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h> 

SoftwareSerial SIM900(7, 8); // RX, TX
    Serial.begin(9600);
    SIM900.begin(19200);

    if (httpStatus.indexOf("+HTTPACTION:0,200,") != -1) {
        int contentLength = getContentLength(httpStatus);
        if (contentLength > 0) {
            String response = readHttpResponse(contentLength);
            if (response.length() == 0) {
                Serial.println("Error: No response received.");
            } else {
                processResponse(response);
            }
        } else {
            Serial.println("Error: Unable to determine content length.");
        }
    } else {
        Serial.println("Error: HTTP action failed.");
    }

String readHttpResponse(int contentLength) {
    String response = "";
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int chunkSize = 29; // Veličina svakog segmenta
    while (bytesRead < contentLength) {
        int bytesToRead = min(chunkSize, contentLength - bytesRead);
        String command = "AT+HTTPREAD=" + String(bytesRead) + "," + String(bytesToRead);
        String part = sendCommand(command);
        String message = extractMessage(part);
        // String part = readResponse();
        response += message;
        bytesRead += bytesToRead;
        Serial.print("Bytes read: ");
        Serial.print(bytesRead);
        Serial.print(" of ");
        Serial.println(contentLength);
    }
    Serial.println("Complete response received: ");
    Serial.println(response);
    return response;
}
String sendCommand(String command) {
    Serial.print("Sending command: ");
    Serial.println(command);
    SIM900.println(command);
    return readResponse();
}
String readResponse(unsigned long timeout) {
    String response = "";
    unsigned long startTime = millis();
    while (millis() - startTime < timeout) {
        while (SIM900.available()) {
            char c = SIM900.read();
            response += c;
        }
        if (response.endsWith("OK\r\n") || response.endsWith("ERROR\r\n")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    Serial.println("Response received: G~");
    Serial.println(response);
    Serial.println("G");
    return response;
}


Console output:
3:46:34.700 -> Sending command: AT+HTTPREAD=232,10
03:46:34.767 -> Response received: G~
03:46:34.799 -> AT+HTTPREAD=232,10
03:46:34.832 ->
03:46:34.832 -> +HTTPREAD:10
03:46:34.832 -> nGrazia"}]
03:46:34.864 -> OK
03:46:34.864 ->
03:46:34.864 -> G
03:46:34.864 ->
03:46:34.864 -> Bytes read: 242 of 242
03:46:34.897 -> Complete response received:
03:46:34.930 ->
03:46:34.930 -> Error: No response received.
As you can see in method readResponse variable "response" has value and it is printed (between G~ and G in console), but return value is empty. Any idea why is this happening?
I'm working with Arduino and sim900.
Thank you in advance.

Either something went wrong inside of extractMessage() (which you didn't show us), or you've simply run out of RAM on your Uno, which causes strings to be silently truncated.

@jasonharper Thanks for the answer. I've removed extractMessage and left full message response in part variable and checked available memory and realized neither of that is the problem. Available memory is 191 bytes and part length is 55. It just fails to concatenate part to response even though part is not empty.

Instead of trying to write your own parser, use a library such as TinyGSM.

@hcheung You are life saver! Thank you so much! You invented a wheel for me :)
